# Should I use single SQLite3 .db file or multiple files for every table?

Tags: sqlite

Will using multiple files (= multiple cursors) for each table increase performance under big load? I'm asking this question because I heard somewhere that SQLite has a limited amount of actions per some amount of time in its cursor, so I thought making multiple cursors will break this limitation